# Is there a preferred way to install plugins in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

There exist a couple of way to install plugins in Eclipse:

1. Marketplace installation
2. Install Software through Update Site
3. Dropping plugin files under eclipse/dropins
4. Go to the `eclipse/plugins` directory and install the plug-in there manually.

Is there a preferred way to install plugins in Eclipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Option 1 (Marketplace installation) is consistent with Eclipse user experience. But a plugin needs to be approved by Moderation Team of the Marketplace. If a plugin (or other product) is good enough, that is clearly an option. Here's an [entry point](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/quickstart) for this way.
- Option 2 (Eclipse Update Site) is also consistent and good. It needs no moderation. But it requires an update site (a [manual](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_create_an_update_site_%28site.xml%29%3F) on how to make one, found here). Also it requires some instruction, giving the user a URL for Update Site. Although, it's no big deal to copy and paste a link.
  A good example of option 2: [eclipse-zencoding plugin](https://github.com/sergeche/eclipse-zencoding#installation)
- Options 3 and 4 are no good:

  - Inconsistent with common user experience.
  - Prone to bugs.
  - No automatic updates.

UPD: There is a whole section of Eclipse Reference on this topic: [Packaging and delivering Eclipse based products](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fproduct.htm&cp=46_0_21).

Comment: By a fortune, I've been researching on this question the whole day. )

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Quite confusing indeed to have some many options to install plugins, glad to see clear now thanks to you and E-Riz!

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, if the desired feature/plugin(s) is available in the Marketplace, that's the most user-friendly way to install. However, not every producer of plugins makes the effort to publish them in the marketplace. In that case, using the **Install New Software...** wizard with an update site is the next option.

Using the `dropins` folder, while officially supported, can be quite error-prone and difficult to troubleshoot. I consider it a last resort if the features/plugins don't publish an update site.

Just placing things into the `plugins` folder is *not* supported and basically will not work. p2 (Eclipse's provisioning framework) does not cooperate when the `plugins` folder is changed behind its back. A long time ago (in a galaxy far, far away) it was an option, but even then it was very error-prone.